# How do you access or determine what Tabulator params are set/needed

Tags: tabulator

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/edit shows an example:

```
//define lookup function
function paramLookup(cell){
    //cell - the cell component

    //do some processing and return the param object
    return {param1:"green"};
}

//column definition
{title:"Rating", field:"rating", editor:"star", editorParams:paramLookup}
```

How do you then either access the params once set or even determine what params to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at `table.options` where `table` is the tabulator instance and `options` is an object for all of the current Tabulator options.

Here is a fiddle that you can run.  It will write the table options to the document body, but it is very difficult to read.  If you look at the console, it also logs the table instance and the `table.options` object.

https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/j506cvea/4/

You can also look at the prototype to find some other methods that may be useful.  For example, `table.getColumnDefinitions()` returns the table's current column definitions.

Comment: Nice to know, but what does that have to do with lookup (or other) params?

Comment: You get those from inside of the column definition. So you can do table.getColumnDefinitions()[0] to access the column definition of the first column. Try console.logging the definition and you should be able to find what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I misread part of the question. The documentation typically tells you what parameters are required. If you fail to provide a required parameter, it will usually log a warning or error.

Comment: Got it - I think. So if I had a subset of columns that were answers to questions and I needed the data to be set to the answer for a given column, but needed to pass the associated question ID invisibly when saving the column answer, would params be the place to set/get the associated question ID?

Comment: I’m not sure I follow you. It would be best to open a new question, with an example of what you’re trying to accomplish. Even if you do it in regular JavaScript without Tabulator, it’ll help me figure out what you’re trying to have Tabulator do.